# How to close the working form after pressing OK

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am writing this part of code in form2 and want that if i successfully registered and i press OK button then form2 should also close along with it

```
 if (MessageBox.Show("Registered Successfully") == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    Reg_Form f2 = new Reg_Form();
    f2.Close();
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not create a *new* form and close that. You should close the current form. If your code is in form2 as you write, you can reference the current form instance with `this`:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Registered Successfully") == DialogResult.OK)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

`this` can be omitted for brevity, but I wanted to include it in the example to better explain the point - you need to call close on the current instance. The shorter form is simply:

```
Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `this.Close` you don't need to create new instance

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Registered Successfully") == DialogResult.OK)
{
    this.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can close it using  [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx) keyword

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Registered Successfully") == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    this.Close();
  }
```

> The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class and is also used as a modifier of the first parameter of an extension method.